# php generate thumbnail error with path contain "&" symbol

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

let say the path without "&" symbol, this path work fine:

```
$path = 'images/a-a/image1.jpg';  
echo "<img src='thumb.php?filepath=$path'>";
```

but if the path like this, contain "&" symbol:

```
$path = 'images/a-&-a/image1.jpg';  
echo "<img src='thumb.php?filepath=$path'>";
```

it generate black image (error). i have tried with str_replace "&" with ampersand still same error, or htmlspecialchar same error. Anyone please help. Is there any way to solve this without rename all the images folder and the path in database?

Comment: Please show us the output of: `var_dump($path);`

Comment: @Rizier123 this output of var_dump : string(42) "images/a-&-a/image1.jpg"

Comment: @MilanG thanks so much, you made my day... solved. $path = urlencode($path);